# Do lm object coefficients always list intercept first?

Tags: r, linear-regression

In `coef(l)`, where `l` is a object of class "lm", is `(Intercept)` always listed first?

[R's source code for `lm()`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5201e090c1623bb9fa04dbdeed0ab99903643f02/src/library/stats/R/lm.R) is not so straightforward. `lm()` appears to call `lm.fit()`, which gets coefficients by calling a C function with `.Call(C_Cdqrls, x, y, tol, FALSE)`, which ultimately calls a least squares fitting routine in FORTRAN according to [this informative blog post](http://madrury.github.io/jekyll/update/statistics/2016/07/20/lm-in-R.html). I'm not really familiar enough with R internals or actual code to do least squares regression to answer my question.

Comment: It will appear first unless as long as you don't fit a model that doesn't have an intercept.

Comment: @MrFlick then the intercept is just 0? or do you mean something else.

Comment: If you fir a model like `coef(lm(y~x-1, data.frame(x=rnorm(10), y=runif(10))))` then there just isn't an intercept so it's not first. So intercept isn't always the first coefficient, but if you fit a model that has an intercept, then it will be listed first (at least with `lm`)

Comment: @MrFlick Huh, I didn't know that. Can you turn the comment into an answer? Do you know it's listed first from the code internals or just experience?

Answer (score 0):

No, only when you have an intercept. Intercept is implicit in formula, but you can specify a model without it using `- 1` or `0 +`:

```
x <- rnorm(20)
y <- rnorm(20, 10)

> coef(lm(y ~ x + I(x^2)))
(Intercept)           x      I(x^2) 
 10.3035412  -0.1506304  -0.3092836 

> coef(lm(y ~ I(x^3) + x - 1))
    I(x^3)          x 
-0.5094851 -0.6598634
```

The coefficients will be listed in the order they appear in the formula. ***If*** there is an intercept, it will be the first. But as in many other situations in R, if you need to obtain the value of a specific component (intercept or any other), it is a good practice to call by it's name. It will return `NA` if the object don't have it:

```
intercept <- coef(model)["(Intercept)"]
```

Comment: do you know that if there is an intercept, it will always be listed first?

Comment: I wouldn't count on any particular order of coefficients.  Use the names.